# RubyのActiveRecordでbelongs_toのデータを含める方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

jsonを返すapiを作っています。

モデルは2つあり、
- post
- user
となっています。

関係は`post >- user`という感じで、ユーザーが複数のポストを持っています。

例えば全ての情報をかえす場合は

```
{
  posts: [{
    id: 1,
    name: title1,
    user: {
      id: 1
      name: name1
    }
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: title2,
    user: {
      id: 1
      name: name1
    }
  }]
}
```

このようなjsonを返したいと考えています。

ただ、`Post.all.to_json`としてしまうと`User`モデルの情報が含まれず、書き方がわかりません。
上記のような形にしたい場合はどのようにコードを書いてJsonを生成するのが良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Post.all.to_json(include: :user)
```

のように、`#to_json`の`include`オプションにリレーション名を指定することで可能です

Answer (score -2):

`to_json belongs_to` で検索しましょう